# Openlayers 3 how to add kml using a string variable?

Tags: kml, openlayers-3

Is there any way to add a kml vector in openlayer 3 like this but the kml is from a string variable?

```
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
              url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/kml/2012-02-10.kml',
              format: new ol.format.KML()
            })
          });
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
var kmlString = result;
var features = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(kmlString);

var KMLvectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
});


var KMLvector = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: KMLvectorSource });

//KMLvector.addFeatures(features);
map.addLayer(KMLvector);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the projection definition and transformation for your kml features.
The kml features exist in `https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/kml/2012-02-10.kml` are projected in `EPSG:4326` while your map is projected in `EPSG:3857`. For kml is common to be projected in `4326` so in most cases the EPSG code for kml should be 4326.

Now back to your problem. Change this line:

`var features = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(kmlString);`

To this:

`var features = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(kmlString,{
dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
});`

Comment: btw i dont use the kml from openlayers. i have a string variable that contains string its projected at 3857 . and i already tried that code but it does not work there's no error but the kml layer doesn't show

Comment: is there any other way to load from a kml from database other than passing it to a string

Comment: Your question was how to load it from string. Better decide what you really want so we are not wasting our time.

Comment: sorry i already figure it out. there is something wrong with my kml file.thanks anyway